# GitHub Api: User followers - paging?

Tags: github, github-api

I am playing with some Javascript and Github API, and I've came to one problem.

Each time, when I try to call for followers of any user who has followers, the callback that I get from the server shows only 30 users. For example:

https://api.github.com/users/vojtajina/followers - 30 followers

and user followers from original website:

https://github.com/vojtajina/followers  - 1,039 followers

My questions is - what is going on? There is no 'next page' in the callback from the server. How can I get all of his/hers followers in the callback?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The max number of items per page is 100, so using the `per_page=100` querystring parameter will increase the result to have 100 users per page:

```
https://api.github.com/users/vojtajina/followers?per_page=100
```

Using the `page` querystring parameter, you have control to pagination. For example, to get the second page, you should add `page=2`:

```
https://api.github.com/users/vojtajina/followers?per_page=100&page=2
```

If you want to get all the followers you have to iterate the pages until you receive an empty array.

---

If you want to use this into a Node.js / JavaScript (on client) app, you can use [`gh.js`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/gh.js)–a library I developed which handles this:

```javascript
var GitHub = require("gh.js");

var gh = new GitHub({
    token: "an optional token"
});

gh.get("users/vojtajina/followers", { all: true } function (err, followers) {
    console.log(err || followers); // do something with the followers
});
```

Comment: Thats great! Thanks for suggestions. I was actually asking for the library. Can I authenticate with this library, so that my limit is higher then 60?

Comment: @uksz Of course, it supports tokens: https://github.com/settings/tokens/new Feel free to open issues if you have any problems/ideas/feature request. :)

Comment: You are great. Thank you, and have a great Sunday!

Comment: Sorry to ask you a question over here but not over the issue (maybe it is faster?). The token doesn't seem to work - when I check how many requests left I have, it seems to me that the request out of 60, not 5000. Is this the only step that I have to make, or is there any other (besides var gh = new GitHub({token:"an optional token"})?

Comment: @uksz Hmm, it *should* work. Replace the token value (`an optional token`) with your token. Then you should get more requests hour rate limit. Again, for such questions, open issues. I try to do my best in replying to everybody. :)